# simulate timestamp in seeds.rb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I want to populate the database by sample data, and for some reason, I also want to simulate `created_at`.
This is my seeds.rb:

```
9.downto(1) do |i|
  product = Product.new(price: 99.99)
  product.created_at = i.days.ago,
  product.save!
end
```

In the database, the result of `rake db:seed` looks like,

`---- 2012-03-03 16:50:30.316886000 Z- 1`

when I need

`2012-03-03 16:50:30.316886000 Z- 1`

How to avoid these `----` symbols in the result?

(db: sqlite3)

update:
I just found that when I use `product.created_at = i.days.ago`,
in callback (`before_save`) `created_at` is `Array`: `[date_value, 1]`. So I can use

```
before_save { self.created_at = self.created_at[0] }
```

and then, value in database will be right (without `----`), but using callbacks doesn't seem like a good way.

Comment: Would `product.created_at = (Date.new - i)` work for you?

Comment: thanks for suggestion, but no, it doesn't work. i get some weird value (`--- -4713-12-25- 1`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
product.created_at = i.days.ago,
```

You need to get rid of the trailing comma, that's why you're ending up with an array for `created_at`. Fix that and you can get rid of the `before_save` callback.

Edit: The reason you are getting the `---` in there is because whatever ORM you are using is trying to serialize the Array and it's turning it into YAML.